# How to dynamically create Input Fields in VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to dynamically add or remove input fields on the go.

I got a simple solution from here https://smarttutorials.net/dynamically-add-or-remove-input-textbox-using-vuejs/, which works. However saving input values in the database stops it's functionality.

Component Code:

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.name" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.party" />
  <span>
    <i
      class="fas fa-minus-circle"
      @click="remove(k)"
      v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)"
    ></i>
    <i
      class="fas fa-plus-circle"
      @click="add(k)"
      v-show="k == inputs.length-1"
    ></i>
  </span>
</div>
<button @click="addCandidate">
  Submit
</button>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        inputs: [
          {
            name: "",
            party: ""
          }
        ]
      };
    },
    methods: {
      add(index) {
        this.inputs.push({ name: "", party: "" });
      },
      remove(index) {
        this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
      },
      addCandidate() {
        axios
          .post("/candidates", this.inputs)
          .then(response => {})
          .catch(error => {});
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

I always get a 422 error, saying the input field is empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a Vue problem. Before you send an array you'll need to call `JSON.stringify()` on it, then decode it on the server with Laravel. Example:

```
foreach(json_decode($request -> input('my_prop_name ')) as $my_object_in_array)
{
  print_r($my_object_in_array); // this is your object name/party
}
```

Vue code working like magic. :)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      inputs: [{
        name: '',
        party: ''
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    add () {
      this.inputs.push({
        name: '',
        party: ''
      })
      console.log(this.inputs)
    },

    remove (index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
    },

    addCandidate () {
      axios
        .post('/candidates', {
          my_prop_name: JSON.stringify(this.inputs)
        })
        .then(response => {})
        .catch(error => {})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id=app>
  <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.party">
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)">Remove</i>
      <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" @click="add(k)" v-show="k == inputs.length-1">Add fields</i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button @click="addCandidate">
    Submit
  </button>
</div>
```